# What symbol will represnt a text file in a flow chart?

Tags: python, flowchart

So I just need to know what symbol in a flow chart will represent a text file in python.
The text file is used to see if there is a match in what the user has entered and data in a text file to give a solution if found.
it's hard to decide which symbol it is. **Please state the name of the symbol!**
Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking us to read the manual for your flowcharting program and find out the name it uses for a file symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the flowchart symbol for a file is a rectangle with a folded-up corner, meant to depict a piece of paper.

Comment: what is the name of the symbol?

Comment: Are you asking what your flowcharting program calls it?  I don't know.  I would try looking for things called "File", "External File", or perhaps "Document".

Comment: do you mean 'internal file'?

Comment: I imagine that different flowcharting programs might have slightly different names for the same thing.  If you need the specific exact name that your flowcharting program uses, read the manual...

Comment: I'm using Microsoft excel to make the flow chart. and I couldn't find the shape based on the description you have given me. (doesn't have a manual)

Comment: "Stored Data" might be the closest symbol.  Excel does have a "Document" symbol, but I think that's intended for actual paper printouts.

Comment: Unicode defines a range of symbols for that: [Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs](http://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/miscellaneous-symbols-and-pictographs/). You can find a "Document" symbol.